# Can't access the subscribe() value out side the method in angular2

Tags: angular

unable to use subscribe value out side the subscribe() method. Please help how to access the myData out side the method.

```
ngOnInit() {

this.subscription = this.messageService.getMessage().subscribe(function(data){
    console.log(data);
    this.myData = data;
    console.log(this.myData ); // able to print the data

})
    console.log(this.myData ); // undefined is printing
    this.sampleData = {id: 1080, code: "123"};    
}

sample.html

{{myData}} -- [not printing the object] // unable to access inside subscribe method data
{{sampleData}}  -- [Printing the object data]  // able to access out side subscribe method data

        <tr>
            <td><label>Location</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" maxlength="5" tabindex="1" name="locationCode" [(ngModel)] = myData.location ></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><label>Name</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="txtName" maxlength="10" tabindex="2" [(ngModel)]=myData.name ></td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: the data is not available by the time you log outside the subscription, what do you want to do with that data?

Comment: You need to move the code into the function you pass to `subscribe(...)`. It is called when the data becomes available (response from the server). Use `(data) => {` instead of `function(data) {` to be able to access `this` inside this function.

Comment: @Alejandro Camba, myData is object, this object data I want to populate in edit page. Unable to access the mydata in my html page.

Comment: in your [(ngModel)] = myData.locCd remember the " " so,  [(ngModel)] = "myData.locCd", but this is no longer related to the question you posted you should edit it and post your code where you are trying to edit that component property from your input.

Comment: @Alejandro Camba I have updated the code, please look into

Answer (score 2):

> The data you subscribe is brought in a asynchronous manner , and the
>   console.log is printed in a synchronous manner.

You need to get the data i:e myData inside the subscribe and  do all the processing there .

```
this.subscription = this.messageService.getMessage().subscribe(function(data){
    console.log(data);
    this.myData = data;
    ...//do all the processing here

})
```

Comment: Hi Rahul, I am unable to use myData object in html page for EX:
sample.html
<tr>
 <td><label>Location Code</label></td>
 <td><input type="text" maxlength="5" tabindex="1" name="locationCode" [(ngModel)] = myData.locCd ></td>
</tr>

Comment: You can use the data just do a {{myData}}. And put this method of subscribe inside onInit

Comment: Yes Rahul, I am writing this code inside ngOnInit() method only, I have updated the question clearly, please look it.

Comment: add some thing like this  `{{myData?.location}}` @arjun

Comment: also it should be `[(ngModel)] = "{{myData?.location}}"`

Comment: No Luck, Seems we are unable to access the subscribe() method data in template. If any body have working copy? please post here, It may help to me. Thanks for response.

Comment: can you create a stackblitz or plunker demo , we do it regularly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155518/discussion-between-arjun-and-rahul-singh).

Answer (score 0):

Do `[(ngModel)] = "myData.location"` instead of `[(ngModel)] = myData.location`